# Directive not working on Ionic 3.19 + Angular 4.1.3

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I am trying to create a Directive to transform input characters to Uppercase when user types, but I am getting to believe that this is impossible.

What I have:
uppercase.directive.ts:

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[UpperCaseInput]',
  host: {
    '[value]': 'UpperCaseInput',
    '(input)': 'format($event.target.value)'
  }
})
export class UppercaseInput implements OnInit {

  @Input() uppercase: string;
  @Output() uppercaseChange: EventEmitter < string > = new EventEmitter < string > ();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uppercase = this.uppercase || '';
    this.format(this.uppercase);
  }

  format(value) {
    value = value.toUpperCase();
    this.uppercaseChange.next(value);
  }
}
```

uppercase.directive.module.ts:

```
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  UppercaseInput
} from './uppercase.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UppercaseInput],
  imports: [],
  exports: [UppercaseInput]
})
export class UppercaseInputModule {}
```

Then I import the module inside my app.import.ts:

```
import {
  UppercaseInputModule
} from '../directives/uppercase.directive.module';
...
export const MODULES = [UppercaseInputModule];
```

And in my app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    MODULES,
    SharedModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

When I try something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ([UpperCaseInput])='user.name' placeholder="Your name here" />
```

I get:
**Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'UpperCaseInput' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.**

So, what am I doing wrong here? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-input[UpperCaseInput]'
})
export class UppercaseInput implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.applyUppercase();
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event.target'])
  onkeyup(input: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {
    this.applyUppercase();
  }

  applyUppercase(): void {
    let input = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

    if (input) {
      input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

And in the *html* you change the *input tag*:

```
<ion-input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name here" UpperCaseInput></ion-input>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but the main problem was where I had imported the directive module, all set now, thanks a lot.